# Convert 12bit to decimal

Tags: c

I would like to convert 12bit to decimal number in C language.

for example if we have:

A1=0x5D
A2=0xA0 (LSB bits in A2 always is 0)

so if we put these together we have:

0x5DA and it is equal to 1498.

could you please guide me how can I do this in C ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1 needs to be shifted 4 bits to the left to make room for the bits of A2, which can be done with `A1 << 4`.

Then A2 needs to be shifted 4 bits to the right to get rid of the extra zeros in the least-significant bits, which can be done with `A2>>4`.

Then the two parts could be combined with `|` operator:

```
(A1 << 4) | (A2 >> 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your definition of *converting it to a decimal number*.

When you do ...

```
int A1 = 0x5D;
int A2 = 0xA0;
int B  = (A1 << 4) | (A2 >> 4); // (*)
```

... then `B` can be used as-if decimal, even though its representation is or may be binary:

```
printf("%d", B);
```

---

The statement `int B  = (A1 << 4) | (A2 >> 4);` can be explained as follows:

- `<<` is left shift, bits will be shifted out, zeroes will fill up
- `>>` is right shift, bits will be shifted out, zeroes will fill up
- `X << Y` means `shift X to the left by Y binary digits`
- `|` combines both operands using bitwise or

In summary: Shifting `A1` by 4 bits to the left introduces four zeros on the least significant side. You then fill it up with `A2` "minus" its four least significant bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this relatively easy in `C`:

```
val = ((A1 << 8) + A2) >> 4;
```

You simply concatenate the two numbers and after that remove the last 4 bits that are always zero.

Comment: I think, it should be `A1 << 8`

Comment: Note: If platform uses 16-bit `int` and `A1` is some signed type, the `>> 4` may replicate the sign bit.